# Dynamic binding and static

Tags: c++, dynamic-binding

I guess i am having some trouble in understanding dynamic bynding.

Suppose we are having 2 classes:

```
class a1{ //..
virtual void print() const;
};

class a2:a1{ //...
void print() const override;
};
```

Why is the following true:

```
a2 item_son;
a1 &item_father = item_son;
item_father->print();
```

the print called is the one of the son.

Comment: After changing your code a little so it compiles, [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/DC4TIF).

Comment: ^ - References aren't pointers

Comment: Do you mean it's actually `a1::print` that is called, instead of `a2::print`? Now is *really* the time to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't get the connection with static/dynamic binding yet

Comment: You should read about `public` members and `public` inheritance

Comment: Sorry, It's a2::print. This makes me confusing.

Comment: Yepp. it must. That's how virtual functions work. Remove `virtual` and `override` to get the opposite (so that `item_father.print();` will call `a1::print()`).

Comment: Thanks, that observation on virtual helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the OP did realize the meaning of `virtual` overloading vs. non-`virtual` overloading of functions. However, I got my sample running, hence, I'd like to publish it:

```
#include <iostream>

class A1 {
  public:
  virtual void print() const
  {
    std::cout << "A1::print() called." << std::endl;
  }
};

class A2: public A1 {
  public:
  void print() const override
  {
    std::cout << "A2::print() called." << std::endl;
  }
};

class B1 {
  public:
  void print() const
  {
    std::cout << "B1::print() called." << std::endl;
  }
};

class B2: public B1 {
  public:
  void print() const
  {
    std::cout << "B2::print() called." << std::endl;
  }
};

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  A2 a2;
  cout << "Calling a2.print(): ";
  a2.print();
  A1 &a1 = a2;
  cout << "Calling a1.print(): ";
  a1.print();
  B2 b2;
  cout << "Calling b2.print(): ";
  b2.print();
  B1 &b1 = b2;
  cout << "Calling b1.print(): ";
  b1.print();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Calling a2.print(): A2::print() called.
Calling a1.print(): A2::print() called.
Calling b2.print(): B2::print() called.
Calling b1.print(): B1::print() called.
```

[**Life demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/12lj5V)